# In gvim, is it possible to have multiple rows of file tabs?

Tags: vim

In gvim, is it possible to have multiple rows of file tabs?

That is, instead of showing left/right arrows to navigate around the tabline (for tabs that don't fit into the tabline), it should "start" a new row of tabs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK, no, unless you intend to change vim's source.

But, if you need that many tabs, now don't take me wrong, but if you need that many tabs you're doing something wrong. "Vim's way" is effective buffer and windows control. There are many nice buffer managers, which help while editing many buffers (files). Try to take advantage of some of them.

Answer (score 2):

`:he setting-tabline` will give you your options available. Might not be exactly what you want but there are a few functions that may help you.

I personally use tabs but get rid of the tabline by setting

```
showtabline=0
```

As I think its just a distraction. You can use a map to `:tabs` to get whats on the tabs and most buffer manager plugins are more efficient for serious editing. (I should qualify this I use the command line Vim editor and prefer a 'zen' like environment or clutterless as much as possible, it might not suit your needs.)

That way I have 3 different tabs with split windows arrangements that I use for different editing tasks that I can cycle through with `gt` and `gT`.

edit:

There is now a plugin that might be worth looking at for this problem.

https://github.com/gcmt/taboo.vim