# display two rows of tabs vim

Tags: vim, tabs

Is there anyway in Vim to display two rows of tabs when you have a lot of files open at once. I don't want the tab overflow-style arrows to appear.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763631/gvim-tabline

Comment: You are mistaking vim tabs and tabs in other applications like browsers. In vim tabs are only viewports (sets of windows with particular layout) and buffers are documents. You should use only the latter for handling multiple files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you asked for.  But I switched from using tabs to plain old multiple buffers with BufExplorer to switch between them.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42

BufExplorer brings up a nice quick list of all the buffer filenames so that you can quickly select one without any need for mousing..

Comment: Ok, after having a look at BufExplorer, I think its better than what i wanted to do. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I've been using it for years now, I always have it mapped to F2.